# AttributeError: 'Styler' object has no attribute 'render'

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

When I using deepchecks encouter this error with my notebook.

```
from deepchecks.tabular.suites import full_suite
suite = full_suite()
suite.run(train_dataset=ds_train, test_dataset=ds_test, model=rf_clf)
```

try a lot with notebook & widgets versions, they are no use.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

the solution is downgrade my pandas version from 2.0.2 to 1.5.3